# how to create sections of m2m field on a form and save the model choices in django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have the following models:

```
PROOF_TYPE_CHOICES =(('A','Address proof'),
                     ('P','PAN card'),
                     )

class DocProof(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1,default='A',
                            choices=PROOF_TYPE_CHOICES
                            )

class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc_proofs = models.ManyToManyField(DocProof)
```

I wish to display the different types of document proof types  in different sections of the vendor form. Example:

```
class VendorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Vendor
    # doc_proofs = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    # queryset=DocProof.objects.all().order_by('-type'),
    # required=True,
    # widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    address_proofs = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=DocProof.objects.filter(type='A').order_by('-type'),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    pan_card = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=DocProof.objects.filter(type='P').order_by('-type'),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

This definitely renders the different sections in the vendor form displayed, but also does not allow me to save the form as it throws errors as the form fieldsets does not include the original 'doc_proofs'. Further, how do I save these choices in the Vendor model as these fields(address_proof,pan_card) are not present on it but only on the form. How exactly do I map them  /override the save method on the model  to save it as 'doc_proofs' ?  Using django 1.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by creating repeated relations to the same Vendor model with different related names as follows In the Vendor model definition added the fields:

```
address_proofs = models.ManyToManyField(DocProof, 
                                        related_name='address_proofs')
pan_card = models.ManyToManyField(DocProof, 
                                     related_name='pan_card')
```

But what is the impact of repeated relations to the same model as above?